# Mongoose schema/model using typescript

Tags: mongoose, typescript

I use this declarations: https://github.com/vagarenko/mongoose-typescript-definitions

The following code works fine but has 2 problems:

```
import M = require('mongoose');

var userSchema:M.Schema = new M.Schema(
    {
        username: String,
        password: String,
        groups: Array
    }, { collection: 'user' });


export interface IUser extends M.Document {
    _id: string;
    username:string;
    password:string;
    groups:Array<string>;

    hasGroup(group:string);
}

userSchema.methods.hasGroup = function (group:string) {
    for (var i in this.groups) {
        if (this.groups[i] == group) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};

export interface IUserModel extends M.Model<IUser> {
    findByName(name, cb);
}

// To be called as UserModel.findByName(...)
userSchema.statics.findByName = function (name, cb) {
    this.find({ name: new RegExp(name, 'i') }, cb);
}

export var UserModel = M.model<IUser>('User', userSchema);
```

**Problem 1:** The smaller problem is, that the function IUser.hasGroup can't be declared inside any typescript class, ... but at least it is typechecked.

**Problem 2:** Is even worse. I define the model method `findByName` and in js this would be valid:  `UserModel.findByName(...)` but I can not get he type of `export var UserModel` to `IUserModel`. So I can't get any typechecking on the model functions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to say something like the following:

```
export var UserModel = <IUserModel>M.model('user', userSchema);
```

Then you will have proper typechecking/intellisense when you reference the UserModel.

Comment: Sounds good. I will check it before I mark the question as correct. Thanks :)

Comment: I've never used those typings for mongoose, I'm not sure if it is some sort of requirement for you. I generally stick to using typings from [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped). The mongoose definitions can be found [here](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/mongoose/mongoose.d.ts), and it has significantly more typings than the one you linked.